# Connect to MSMQ on a remote computer

Tags: c#, msmq, remote-access

I have 2 computers with installed MSMQ, I need to read all private Queues of cumputer by IP address.

For now I have working code for local comp:

```
var machineName = Environment.MachineName;
var queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(machineName);
```

How can I connect to the msmq and get all queue on remote computer by TCP?

Comment: Seems correct, however you should give access to everyone (allow unauthenticated access) on the remote queue. Is it OK?

Comment: Yes, all users have right on all queues

Comment: When I pass to variable machineName = '192.168.1.196' its give me an error

Comment: But then, this should work without any problems. What is the problem?

Comment: What is the error? You should put all these details in your question at the beginning. When you don't, we all lose time as such.

Comment: MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue("Direct=TCP:192.168.1.196\private$\ant_outgoing");

Comment: Are you sure you want to connect to an outgoing queue on the remote machine by the way? (Just assumed by the name of the queue)

Comment: Error is: Operations of the requested type for the specified format name is not supported. For example, you can not remove the immediate queue format name

Comment: I can not use this new MessageQueue("Direct=TCP:192.168.1.196\private$\ant_outgoing"); because I need to get all queues

Comment: But you asked for.. "How can I connect to the queue on remote comtuter like:" Anyways.. You should pass only the computer name, the MSDN documentation states so. But it also states that the machines must be in the same workgroup.

Comment: this works for me: var queueList = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("VPHQ-OOZGUL");

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks but it didnot work for me.